# How to read data into a databricks notebook from Azure blob using Azure Active Directory (AAD)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-databricks

I am trying to read data from some containers into my notebook and write them into the format of spark or pandas dataframe. There are some documentations about using account password, but how can I do it with Azure Active Directory?

Comment: Are you talking about access Azure Blob Storage or Azure Data Lake storage.?When you  say there are some documents, could you please point me one article which talks about accessing Azure Blob storage using Active Directory?

Comment: Blob only. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/team-data-science-process/explore-data-blob This is one example using azure blob account and password instead of AAD to log in, and for the password I meant account password. Actually I found out in newest edition of azure-storage-blob I could use BlobServiceClient to log in: https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/. But I simply just use key vault to log in on databricks notebook and avoid AAD for now.

Comment: In the document you shared, use Azure storage account name and the account key (access key), they haven't used password anywhere. Could you please clarify on the ask?

Comment: Account key is password, like root key for the account. I am asking specifically how to log in with using AAD instead of account name + account key.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, these are the supported methods in Databricks for accessing Azure Blob Storage:

- Mount an Azure Blob storage container
- Access Azure Blob storage directly
- Access Azure Blob storage using the RDD API

**Reference:** [Databricks - Azure Blob Storage](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is several Azure offical documents about accessing Azure Blob using Azure AD, as below.

1. [Authorize access to Azure blobs and queues using Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad)
2. [Authorize access to blobs and queues with Azure Active Directory from a client application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app)
3. [Authorize with Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory) about Authorize requests to Azure Storage

Meanwile, here is my sample code to get the key (account password) of an Azure Storage account for using it in databricks.

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.storage import StorageManagementClient

# Please refer to the second document above to get these parameter values
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id='<your client id>',
    secret='<your client secret>',
    tenant='<your tenant id>'
)

subscription_id = '<your subscription id>'

client = StorageManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

resource_group_name = '<the resource group name of your storage account>'
account_name = '<your storage account name>'

# print(dir(client.storage_accounts))

keys_json_text = client.storage_accounts.list_keys(resource_group_name, account_name, raw=True).response.text

import json
keys_json = json.loads(keys_json_text)
# print(keys_json)
# {"keys":[{"keyName":"key1","value":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==","permissions":"FULL"},{"keyName":"key2","value":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==","permissions":"FULL"}]}'
key1 = keys_json['keys'][0]['value']
print(key1)
```

Then, you can use the account password above to follow the Azure Databricks offical document [Data > Data Sources > Azure Blob Storage](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html) to read data.

Otherwise, you can refer to the Steps 1 & 2 of my answer for the other SO thread [transform data in azure data factory using python data bricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56757785/transform-data-in-azure-data-factory-using-python-data-bricks/56801586#56801586) to read data, as the code below.

```
from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerPermissions
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

account_name = '<your account name>'
account_key = '<your account key>' # the key comes from the code above
container_name = '<your container name>'

service = BaseBlobService(account_name=account_name, account_key=account_key)
token = service.generate_container_shared_access_signature(container_name, permission=ContainerPermissions.READ, expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1),)

blob_name = '<your blob name of dataset>'
blob_url_with_token = f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/{blob_name}?{token}"

import pandas as pd

pdf = pd.read_json(blob_url_with_token)
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
```